# Thunderbird 60 minimise to tray

Tags: thunderbird, system-tray, mozilla

Extensions like [FireTray](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) no longer work with the Thunderbird version 60+ . How can I run thunderbird version 60+ minimised to tray?

I run awesome-wm v4.2.

Comment: There is a fork of the FireTray project which has been updated to work with Thunderbird 60+

`git clone https://github.com/firetray-updates/FireTray`
`cd FireTray/src`
`make build`
The .xpi file will be built which you can load from file from Thunderbird.  

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and Thunderbird 60.2.1

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

The add-on [MinimizeToTray Reanimated](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-reanimated/) works...

Though I fail to see why this basic email client function needs a plugin. TB should support this out of the box.

Comment: It does hide the thunderbird. However, every time I try to open thunderbird from tray, it crushes.